Using a Connection Pool in a Google Cloud Function
I can't figure out how to use a connection pool in a Google Cloud Function (GCF).  It seems like the limitiations of GCFs prevent use of many things, including connection pools.
In our main (app engine) app we use connection pools.  The pools are lazily loaded.  We create a DB object, which contains a pool, that is declared like this:
private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
The first time the DB object is created, pool is null, and a one time initialization occurs.  All future invocations of the DB object now have a connection pool.  Perfect.
This doesn't seem to work as expected with a GCF.  GCFs are stateless.  So when we moved a portion of the application from appengine to a GCF, the connection pool is initialized on every call to the GCF, which is an expensive operation given we use Hikari.
Ok, google says GCFs are stateless, so that makes sense.  Is there a way to do one time initialization from a GCF to retain information (connection pool) between invocations?
Note that we have this same problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging.  How do we perform a one-time initializtion of FCM in a GCF?

Please edit the question to show an example of complete, minimal code that doesn't work the way you expect, not just a line of declaration.

App Engine is almost as "serverless" (marketing not technical term) as Cloud Functions. There is still a server and you get to define global/static values in both (viz ConnectionPool. The behavior is comparable. For each instance (of your application) global variables will be established once.

I wrote this many years ago but it remains relevant Cloud Functions global scope

The code above is the exact code.  I can see, in the logs, that it is being called on each invocation, which surprised me.

Your comment is unclear. An invocation can represent the lifetime of an instance. Invocations created within the lifetime of an instance will share global state. I recreated my trivial Node.JS example in Python (for giggles) and deployed to Cloud Run gen2 and I'm reliably able to see the instance function created once (per instance) and shared by multiple function invocations.

You are correct.  I think the problem in our code was that the one-time initialization was not declared "static".  I can confirm tht the db initialization happens once after deployment.  Future invocations of the function do not go through the initialization.  Thanks to  DazWilkin for helping clear this up.
